# Spivak Chapter 13 Question 39

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have problem understanding the following statements that come from the Answers Book to question 39 of chapter 13 (note I've patched 2-21(c) above):[image]

I have not posted the full question and answer as its lengthy and I only need help with this part.    Specifically I don't see how the second equation is an analogue to the first especially the part with the $1/2$ and the integral which follows.  For a bit of context, the question asks to prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals as you might be able to recognize.

Comment: The $1/2$ comes because of the fact that the integral involves all values of $x, y$ in $[a, b] $ and not just those with $x<y$.

Comment: For any interval $I$, $\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I, j > i} f_{ij}$ is the same as $\frac 12 \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in I} f_{ij}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Unfortunately I'm quite clueless as to the entire integral following the $1/2$.  I can see how the other integrals correspond, because we are just taking an 'infinite' version of the summation.  Can  you please elaborate how the other integral is analogous as suggested?

Comment: Expand that complex looking integral using formula $(a-b)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}-2ab$ and you will see the identity in question at once. Keep track of symbols $x, y, dx, dy$.

Comment: It is more of algebraic manipulation rather than calculus (the only fact needed from calculus is that integration is a linear operation ie $$\int_{a} ^{b} \{pf(x) +qg(x) \}\, dx=p\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx+q\int_{a} ^{b} g(x) \, dx$$ for arbitrary constants $p, q$ and arbitrary integrable functions $f, g$).

Answer (score 0):

First note that symbol $\int_{a}^{b} f^{2}$ means the integral $$A=\int_{a} ^{b} \{f(x)\} ^{2}\,dx$$ and similarly let $$B=\int_{a} ^{b} \{g(x)\} ^{2}\,dx,\,C=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx$$ and the above use of symbols $A, B, C$ is to emphasize that these integrals are constants.

Next we can see that $$\int_{a}^{b} \left\{\int_{a} ^{b} \{f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)\} ^{2}\,dx\right\} \, dy$$ is equal to $$\int_{a}^{b} \left\{A\{g(y)\} ^{2}+B\{f(y)\}^{2}-2Cf(y)g(y)\right\}\, dy$$ (the terms with $y$ in the inner integral are constant as the integration is happening with respect to variable $x$) and this is clearly $AB+AB-2C^{2}$ or $2(AB-C^{2})$ as desired.

Comment: Sorry you might have my understood my problem.  What I don't understand is how that equation is thought of in the first place.  The solution uses the previous proof for Cauchy inequality the first equation in my post as a way of getting to the second equation.  Now as you can see each term in the first seems to correspond nicely to each term in the second.  Except for,  $\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$ and $\int_{a}^{b} \left\{\int_{a} ^{b} \{f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)\} ^{2}\,dx\right\} \, dy$.  This step, from the summation to the integral is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: @helios321: that should have been obvious. From $x_{i} y_{j} - x_{j}y_{i} $ we get the analogous expression $f(x) g(y) - f(y) g(x) $ and the summation is changed to integral. Note that the $x, y$ of summation correspond to $f, g$ of integration. $i, j$ correspond to $dx, dy$.

Comment: Even if we were to expand both $\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$ and $\int_{a}^{b} \left\{\int_{a} ^{b} \{f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)\} ^{2}\,dx\right\} \, dy$  and replace the summation with the integral, its not clear to me how we would get the $1/2$.

Comment: @helios321: the integral equation is not obtained via the summation identity, it is only analogous to it.

Comment: @helios321: I discussed the factor $1/2$ in comments. Note that $\sum_{i<j} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}$.

Comment: Hmm I don't see why $\sum_{i<j} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}$ is true.  Is this true in general for whatever we are summing or just for this $\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$

Comment: @helios321: it is obvious that $$\sum_{i, j} =\sum_{i=j} +\sum_{i<j} +\sum_{i>j} $$ for any expression after $\sum$. For our specific expression the first sum on right for $i=j$ is $0$ (check) and the next two sums for $i<j$ and $i>j$ are equal (because the expression does not change on interchanging roles of $i$ and $j$). I think it should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be the equal partition of $[a,b]$:
$$ P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}, x_i=a+i\frac{b-a}{n},i=0,1,2,\cdots,n. $$
and $t_k\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, $i=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$, $\Delta x=x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{b-a}{n}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^nf^2(t_i)\Delta x\cdot\sum_{i=1}^ng^2(t_i)\Delta x=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)g(t_i)\Delta x\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n[(f(t_i)g(t_j)-f(t_j)g(t_i)]^2\Delta^2
\end{eqnarray}
Letting $n\to\infty$ and using the definition of Riemann integrals, one has
$$ \int_a^bf^2(x)dx\int_a^bg^2(x)dx=\left(\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2+\frac12\int_a^b\int_a^b\left[f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)\right]^2dxdy. $$